# registry keys for Enabling ActiveX in IE on Windows-CE

Tags: security, internet-explorer, windows-registry, windows-ce

Does anyone know what registry keys are used to enable ActiveX in IE on windows-CE devices? I have to configure a lot of these devices. The settings aren't saved when changed in IE itself. I need to get rid of the following message:

> This page provides potentially unsave information to an ActiveX control. Your current security settings prohibit running controls in this manner. As a result, this page may not display correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an MSDN entry which explains it all:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908714.aspx